# Pandas DataFrame: How to print single row horizontally?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Single row of a DataFrame prints value side by side, i.e. column_name then columne_value in one line and next line contains next column_name and columne_value. For example, below code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[100,200,300],[400,500,600]])
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # other operations goes here....
    print row
```

Output for first row comes as

```
0    100
1    200
2    300
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Is there a way to have each row printed horizontally and ignore the datatype, Name? Example for the first row:

```
0    1    2
100  200  300
```

Comment: The answer below matches what you want, but a common use-case would be wanting a single line without the header.  For that I'd suggest just doing something like `list(row)` or `dict(row)`.  Can easily be formatted such as: `'\t'.join(list(row).astype(str))`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

use the `to_frame` method then transpose with `T`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[100,200,300],[400,500,600]])
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row.to_frame().T)

     0    1    2
0  100  200  300
     0    1    2
1  400  500  600
```

---

***note:***
This is similar to @JohnE's answer in that the method `to_frame` is syntactic sugar around `pd.DataFrame`.

In fact if we [follow the code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.19.1/pandas/core/series.py#L1126-L1145)

```
def to_frame(self, name=None):
    """
    Convert Series to DataFrame
    Parameters
    ----------
    name : object, default None
        The passed name should substitute for the series name (if it has
        one).
    Returns
    -------
    data_frame : DataFrame
    """
    if name is None:
        df = self._constructor_expanddim(self)
    else:
        df = self._constructor_expanddim({name: self})

    return df
```

Points to `_constructor_expanddim`

```
@property
def _constructor_expanddim(self):
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
    return DataFrame
```

Which you can see simply returns the callable `DataFrame`

Comment: Thanks!  That was a great recovery ;-)  And very good explanation of the difference.

Comment: hi, how to do it from horizontal to vertical

Answer (score 10):

Use the transpose property:

```
df.T

     0    1    2
0  100  200  300
```

Comment: What if df has multiple rows like df = pd.DataFrame([[100,200,300],[400,500,600]]). How can each row be printed like that?

Comment: Amend your OP you reflect that part of the question and your expected output with such a dataframe

Comment: Updated the question. Thanks

Comment: What is the output that you want?  Do you want each row to be a separate column?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like there should be a simpler answer to this, but try turning it into another DataFrame with one row.

```
data = {x: y for x, y in zip(df.columns, df.iloc[0])}
sf = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0])
print(sf.to_string())
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorta combining the two previous answers, you could do:

```
for index, ser in df.iterrows():
    print( pd.DataFrame(ser).T )

     0    1    2
0  100  200  300
     0    1    2
1  400  500  600
```

Basically what happens is that if you extract a row or column from a dataframe, you get a series which displays as a column.  And doesn't matter if you do `ser` or `ser.T`, it "looks" like a column.  I mean, series are one dimensional, not two, but you get the point...

So anyway, you can convert the series to a dataframe with one row.  (I changed the name from "row" to "ser" to emphasize what is happening above.)  The key is you have to convert to a dataframe first (which will be a column by default), then transpose it.

Comment: I often use a reconstruction to solve problems.  plus one from me.